# Is there a difference between DISTINCT colname and DISTINCT(colname)?

Tags: sql, distinct

I've seen both versions around. On iSeries DB2 you can use either and as far as I can tell they do the same thing. Is there a difference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is no difference because DISTINCT is a keyword and **not** a function call.

It's the same difference as between `SOME_COLUMN` and `(SOME_COLUMN)` (without any keyword in front)

Comment: Some experimentation shows that this is correct - the parenthesis do not add anything. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you have only one column in your select, then there is no difference.

However when you use distinct outside as -

```
select disctinct col1, col2, col3 from table
```

It applies distinct on the group tuple of (col1, col2, col3).

Finally there is no difference in using distinct as `select distinct` or `select distinct()`

Comment: What about `DISTINCT(col1), col2, col3`? Would that return the same as your query? a_horse's answer indicates that it would.

Comment: @Michael - I tried out. You can use it as given in your comment, however there is not difference. distinct is applied on whole tuple.